# CakePHP: belongsTo with null value

Tags: cakephp, model, foreign-keys, relational-database, belongs-to

I have a model which has a belongsTo relation which is not required.

```
Banana belongsTo Basket
banana.basket_id can be null
```

Which means that a banana can belong to a basket, but doesn't have to.

The save operation `Banana->save(array('Banana' => array('basket_id' => null, 'weight' => 50)));` works OK, but when I read, I get this result:

```
array(
   'Banana' => array('id' => 10, 'basket_id' => null, 'weight' => 50),
   'Basket' => array('id' => null, 'bannana_count' => null)
)
```

Of course, I could filter it out in afterFind, but I would rather see to have no Basket in the resulting array if basket_id is null. What to do?

Using CakePHP 2.3.6.

Answer (score 3):

Since the Model uses a LEFT JOIN to retrieve related model's data with belongsTo relation, the values of the related fields are exactly what you would get in a select result with a null foreign key value - null values in every column.

The solution is to filter these related models from the result array in the afterFind callback.

```
//Banana model

public function afterFind($results, $primary = false){
   if (isset($results['Basket']) && $results['Basket']['id'] === null) {
      unset($results['Basket']);
   }
   if (isset($results[0])){
       foreach($results as $key => $value){
          if (isset($value['Basket']) && $value['Basket']['id'] === null){
             unset($results[$key]['Basket']);
          }
       }
   }

   //If you forget this, nothing will happen...
   return $results;
}
```

Of course, you might want to set it to `false` instead of unsetting it, or maybe an empty array, but since I found no convention on this, suggestions are most welcome.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `type` key in your association to force an INNER join instead of the default LEFT join.

```
class Banana extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Basket' => array(
            'type'  => 'inner',
            'conditions' => array('Banana.basket_id = Basket.id')
        )
    );
}
```

Docs: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#belongsto

Comment: I have created a unit test to check this. If you make an INNER JOIN, you end up with an empty resultset (same as in SQL). You can see the test here: https://gist.github.com/dizyart/5892935

Comment: I added conditions to my answer, if this still doesn't work, please post the SQL query that is being generated.

Comment: INNER does not show anything if there is not a match. I think he would that not existent association should not show null columns..

Comment: @giuseppe "but I would rather see to have no Basket in the resulting array if basket_id is null"

Comment: but the type=>inner will hide the Banana as well